# Air 11" i7 2011 fans come on, never turn off

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, temperature

I bought a new MBA 11" i7, it's about two weeks old.

I've noticed that as soon as the fans come on, they Never turn off. If I watch a video, or do any slightly heavy lifting, the CPU hits 70C, the fans come on at +6000rpm and never turn off.

Even if the CPU load is less than 1% for an hour or more, the fans stay on full-blast and the CPU temp stays at ~67C and the case at ~35C.
The room is normal temperature, it's sitting on a desk.

The only way I've found of making the fans turn off is to make the Mac sleep for a while.

Is this a known issue? Are other people having similar problems? What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Same here, MBA 13" i7. Resetting the SMC does not help, CPU load nearing 0%, CPU temp at 70C and fans: full throttle. *very* annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The fans are controlled by the [System Management Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller) (SMC).

The first thing to try when troubleshooting a fan issue is resetting that SMC. In fact, Apple says this:

> After performing normal troubleshooting, these symptoms may indicate
>   that an SMC reset may be necessary: [...] The computer's fans run at high speed although the computer is
>   not experiencing heavy usage and is properly ventilated.

Apple has [directions for all models](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964), but I'll excerpt how to do it on your MacBook Air:

> - Shut down the computer.
> - Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to    the Mac if its not already connected.
> - On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option    keys and the power button at the same time.
> - Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
> - Press the power button to turn on the computer.

One other thing you can try is the app [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/?p=134), which claims to allow you to exercise some degree of control over your computer's fans.

This is about all you can do as a consumer; if there is still a problem you will need to take your computer to an Apple Store.

Comment: I'll give it a go.